# Show that $ f(z) = e^{\bar{z}}$ is not complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

$e^{\bar{z}} = e^{x-iy} = e^x. e^{-iy} = e^x(cos(y) - i sin(y) ) = e^xcos(y) - i e^x sin(y) 
 \implies u = Re(e^xcos(y) - i e^x sin(y)) = e^xcos(y) , v = Im (e^xcos(y) - i e^x sin(y)) = - e^x sin(y)$
Using Cauchy Riemann's Theorem:

$u_x = e^xcos(y) \neq -e^xcosy(y) = v_y$ and $u_y = -e^x sin(y) \neq e^x sin(y) = -v_x$ hence $f(z)$ is not complex differentiable. Which means it's not holomorphic.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: You can as well show that $e^z+e^{\bar z}$ is not holomorphic as it is real valued and nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps less work consider the complex derivative at $0$
$$\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{e^{\bar{w}}-1}{w}$$.

if $w=h+0i$ , (Approaching through real axis) then

$$\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{e^{\bar{w}}-1}{w}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{\bar{h}}-1}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h}-1}{h}=1$$.

If $w=0+ik$ ,(approaching through imaginary axis)

$$\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{e^{\bar{w}}-1}{w}=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{e^{-ik}-1}{ik} = -1$$.

As two limits are different, the derivative does not exist.

But yes , your work is correct. Using Cauchy-Riemann equations you can say that since it does not satisfy them, it cannot be complex differentiable.